# Begginer in entity component system

Tags: entity-component-system

I just got myself deep into entity component system and loved the idea. I already understand the basics behind it but the details is where most of porblems hide in. So i wonder if anyone could help me get over it?

1. What is the entity-component structure should be? I've seen two ways to implement this - have entity as object/struct and having as variables inside. Second, having arrays or maps of component where index of array or int in the map represents the ID of entity. Which way is better?
2. If the first method with entities as legit objects is better, then how should I find entities with specific components for systems? Am I supposed to loop through every single entity and then through it's array of component to find out if it has this specific component or not? The same logic can be applied to having maps fo different components as i once again need to loop through the map to find if it has specific id.
3. If the second method with arrays is true, then what if i have a component like "PlayerController" which is only assigned to one entity but there will still be a whole array of these components (Just nulls, but those also occupy 64 bits). Just in case - i will need the whole array as index of an item in the array is what actually represents id of an entity so i will need array at least the size of id of the entity which has this component, but might as well be larger than that due to generalization

It is stange how such a beautiful architecture doesn't have much information online, only libraries (and tutorials to those) which you have to look into if you want to undersand the depths.

Comment: Shameless plug but maybe the [ECS back and forth](https://skypjack.github.io/tags/#ecs) series can help you to understand the main designs for that?

Answer (score 0):

For data type - Dicts/Tables/Structs are best. Objects can really hinder you because you might be tempted to make what could be system-level functions into helper functions. Might come back to bite you later. To build entities with tables, there is a concept of using Assemblages/Archetypes to stitch entities together easily.

The storage method is largely dependent on your language. If it can benefit from cache optimization where the data is stored in a continuous block of memory, it matters. However, for C++/Java and langs built on top that use "magic" pointers they will not benefit from cache optimization (I use Lua, this is only what people have told me on reddit). The tables are continuous within themselves, but not necessarily continuous with each other. So it doesn't matter too much.

If you have control over memory allocation, then you have to weigh the single benefit/drawback -

- Centralized Entity storage requires less overhead to look up components  because they're in the same entity table. However, every system's loop needs to start with an `if component == true` statement to determine if it should operate on the entity or skip it. If's are cheap, though.
- De-Centralized Entity storage does not need an if-check, so the systems never waste time checking entities that don't need their attention. However, there's the extra overhead of updating (co)dependent components in other arrays as a system has to search potentially for longer to find the things it needs. This overhead is increased with more dependencies, so making components as independent as possible is best practice (but not easy). You can get around this some by turning co-dependent components into sub-components of a larger component (so, a table).

Either way, you have to profile your code. The Centralized approach is better if most entities have most components. The De-Centralized approach is more flexible with entities whose components vary greatly. Ultimately, pick what you're comfier with.

To answer your 3rd bullet point (if I understand), you only store useful info in the De-Centralized model. So let's say you have a player and 19 enemies, and the player has a "Player-Input" component. The Player would be entered into the Player-Input component table, and the Player-Input System would look at that **one** component table with the **one** player entry to pass it input. You don't need 19 nulls, that defeats the point of De-Centralization. Alternatively, you can make an "Input" system that handles both Controller input and AI input, but the two can be separate systems. It's up to you.